# Not able to copy file in docker file which is downloaded in github actions

Tags: python, docker, github-actions, fastapi

I can able to see the `.pkl` which is downloaded using `actions/download-artifact@v3` action in work directory along with `Dockerfile` as shown below,

[image]

When I try to `COPY` file inside Dockefile, I get a file not found error.

[image]

How to copy the files inside docker image that are downloaded(through github actions) before building docker image?

Here is [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/dockerfile-support-for-github-actions#user) from github on docker support, but I didn't get exactly how to solve my issue. Any help would be really appreciated!!

**Dockerfile:**

```
name: Docker - GitHub workflow

env:
  CONTAINER_NAME: xxx-xxx

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]
  pull_request:
    branches: ["main"]


permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read

jobs:
  load-artifacts:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: dev
    env:
      output_path: ./xxx/xxx_model.pkl
    
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Download PPE model file
        run: |
            az storage blob download --container-name ppe-container --name xxx_model.pkl -f "${{ env.output_path }}"
            
      - name: View output - after
        run: |
          ls -lhR
      
      - name: 'Upload Artifact'
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: ppe_model
          path: ${{ env.output_path }}

  
  build:
    needs: load-artifacts
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      ACR: xxxx
      
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        id: download
        with:
          name: ppe_model
          # path: ${{ env.model_path }}

      - name: Echo download path
        run: echo ${{steps.download.outputs.download-path}}
      
      - name: View directory files
        run: |
          ls -lhR -a

      - name: Build container image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: false
          tags: ${{ env.ACR }}.azurecr.io/${{ env.CONTAINER_NAME }}:${{ github.run_number }}
          file: ./Dockerfile
```

Comment: what is the build context of docker image, relative paths are relative to build context

Comment: @SankethB.K Not sure. How to check that? or How to make sure it's pointing to the right location? Can please provide it as answer, if it's lengthy in comments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your workflow file, you're not specifying the context:

```yaml
      - name: Build container image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: false
          tags: ${{ env.ACR }}.azurecr.io/${{ env.CONTAINER_NAME }}:${{ github.run_number }}
          file: ./Dockerfile
```

By default, that means that `docker/build-push-action` uses a [git context](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#git-context). That will re-clone your repository... without your model.

The fix, then, is to specify a [path context](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#path-context), like this:

```yaml
      - name: Build container image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          push: false
          tags: ${{ env.ACR }}.azurecr.io/${{ env.CONTAINER_NAME }}:${{ github.run_number }}
          file: ./Dockerfile
```